# How can I add a separate template for the user login form?

Tags: 8, theming

So I want to create a separate user login page for my website.

I create a twig file called page--user--login.html.twig which is great for the outer container. I still want to edit the form divand or the block div. But with debugger on It doesn't give me suggestions for creating a custom form or block twig file just for just the login form.

I can create individual form elements for the login but I want to edit the form div or block div itself without affecting anything else.

Any suggestions?

Comment: The level of detail you are talking about involves things like hook_form_alter, and individual hook_theme_suggestions_alter per form element. You should not be writing raw HTML forms in twig templates.

Comment: if you open up form.html.twig you get a simple form html tag, that's all I want but it needs to be separate from any other generic forms on the website. I'm not interested in writing a raw HTML form. I just want a separate twig file only for the login form.

Answer (score 1):

You can add a theme name suggestion in a [hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Render%21theme.api.php/function/hook_theme_suggestions_HOOK_alter/8.2.x):

```
function mytheme_theme_suggestions_form_alter(&$suggestions, $variables) {
  if ($variables['element']['#form_id'] == 'user_login_form') {
    $suggestions[] = 'form__user_login_form';
  }
}
```

If you want to add suggestions for form elements you need some more code. See the file [themable_forms.module](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/themable_forms/tree/themable_forms.module) from the module [Themable forms](https://www.drupal.org/project/themable_forms). This is the only code file in this module and it is a good example how you can approach this in form alter, preprocess form element and theme suggestions hooks.

Comment: This didn't work for me. I try changing user_login_form to user-login-form and I was to have user-login-forms for the inputs but not a suggestion for the <form> itself. I'll play around with this some more but I think I'll just end up using an if statement on form.html.twig and load the added attributes I want to <form> tag among other things.

Comment: OK, this was only the start. See the edited answer where you can go from there.